# Can't find the right GCC

Tags: gcc, path, homebrew, reinstall

GCC was reinstalled on my mac through brew, but when I did `which gcc`, it returned `/usr/bin/gcc`, instead of  `/usr/local/bin/gcc`.

I restarted my computer, but it did not help. `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/Users/myname/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Comment: Do you have a `gcc` binary in the directory `/usr/local/bin/gcc`?

Comment: @MarkFarrugia @snoopy Yes, it's `/usr/local/bin/gcc@ -> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.3.0_1/bin/gcc-6`

Comment: Have you tried creating a symbolic link? Use a command similar to the following: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.3.0_1/bin/gcc-6 gcc`

Comment: Try to remove anaconda from your $PATH.

Comment: [sorry, I was not able to connect to internet until now]. The reason is `brew install gcc` does not create `gcc` binary, but `gcc-7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is brew install gcc does not create gcc binary, but gcc-7